# Sum value from db in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sum

I'm trying to Sum the value from database to other value. But It keeps only insert the value not the sum of the value. Any ideas?

```
foreach ($isisjkirims as $key => $isisjkirim)  
{  
  IsiSJKirim::where('IsiSJKir', $isisjkir[$key])  
  ->update(['QSisaKemInsert' => 'QSisaKemInsert' + $qtertanda[$key]]);  
}                                      ^
                                i think this one
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get data first and then update:

```
$data = IsiSJKirim::where('IsiSJKir', $isisjkir[$key])->first();
$data->update(['QSisaKemInsert' => (int)$data->QSisaKemInsert + (int)$qtertanda[$key]]);
```